# Remove carriage return end of variable

Tags: bash

I'm getting really strange output for this program. What is the "Carriage Return" doing, and how to remove it - missing single quote in the end? Why is the letter "T" missing? How to write code to correct this?

code i'm using

```
#!/bin/bash

export DATABASE_LIST="/opt/halogen/crontab/etc/db_stat_list.cfg"
export v3=""

while read -r USERID ORACLE_SID2
do
 v3="This is '${ORACLE_SID2}' "
 echo $v3
done < <(tac $DATABASE_LIST)
```

output

```
'his is 'OT1SL80
'his is 'OT1SL010
```

The file I'm reading from is not corrupt and is small one with two lines

```
[oracle@ot1sldbm001v test2]$ cat /opt/halogen/crontab/etc/db_stat_list.cfg
asp_dba/dba OT1SL010
asp_dba/dba OT1SL80
```

Thank you

Comment: You have `This is 'OT1SL80<CARRIAGE RETURN>'`... which translates to `'` overwriting `T`. You need to remove the CR _before_ variable substitution happens. I suggest piping to `tr -d '\r'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DATABASE_LIST file is in DOS/Windows format, with carriage return + linefeed at the end of each line. Unix uses just linefeed as a line terminator, so unix tools treat the carriage return as part of the content of the line. You can keep this from being a problem by telling the `read` command to treat the carriage return as whitespace (like spaces, tabs, etc), since `read` automatically removes whitespace from the beginning and end of lines:

```
...
while IFS="$IFS"$'\r' read -r USERID ORACLE_SID2
    ...
```

Note that since this assignment to `IFS` (which basically lists the whitespace characters) is a prefix to the `read` command, it only applies to that one command and doesn't have to be set back to normal afterward.

Comment: thank you Gordon, I spent hours not thinking it was a DOS/Windows issue, though I have had this problem before. Thanks for the code too. It is working now. I removed file and recreated it properly

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I was in a fix till I saw your fix :)